# MongoDB get document nested array by id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a processes document with a nested attachments array, I want to return get the *fileName* with the processes _id and attachment _id.

[image]

I have tried many options, my latest attempt still return all items from the attachments array. I only want the attachment that matches the attachment id past in.

```
db.getCollection('processes').find(
{$and: [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5a9455d7854cd987a40b1ba4") }, 
{ "attachments._id" : ObjectId("5a983da6201ba5a2302fb38f") }]},
{'attachments._id': 1, 'attachments.fileName': 1}
)
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) in projection to get only one filtered subdocument from nested array:

```
db.getCollection('processes').find(
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5a9455d7854cd987a40b1ba4") },
    { attachments: { $elemMatch: { _id: ObjectId("5a983da6201ba5a2302fb38f") } } } )
```

Comment: Many thanks Mickl!, That works exactly how I wanted to.